# How to securely host file on RHEL server and enable download for user

Tags: security, download, rhel, large-files

I have programmed an application that users can use to process genome data. This application relies on a 10GB database file, that users have to download in order to run the application. At the moment, I have stored this file on Google Drive, but the download bandwith is limited, so if a number of users download the file on a certain day, it will not work for others and they will get errors running the application.

My solution would be to host the file on our  research server, create a user that only has access rights to this folder and nothing else, and make the file downloadable from the server via scp within the application (which is open source) through that user.

My question now is, is this safe to do or are people potentially able to hack into our server? If this method would be a security risk, what would be a better way to provide this file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question (I think there's no good answer), but wouldn't it be better to offer this as a service, and only host the large file yourself? In other words, would this need to work offline? Or is the processing too much for a shared service?

Comment: Is this secure? Generally, yes, depending on implementation. Can people hack your server? Also depending on your implementation. You'll need to keep it updated, set up firewalls ect.

Answer (score 0):

Aloha

You can setup something like free Seafile https://www.seafile.com/en/home/, or ask the admin to set it up for you which is pretty secure like a self hosted google drive with 2fa authentication.

Another nice and easy tool is Filebrowser on github (https://github.com/filebrowser/filebrowser)

I would not really advice giving people shell/scp access inside your network.
And hosting anything inside a company network is in general not wisest idea, there is a always a risk involved.

I would setup a Seafile/filebrowser solution at a cheap rented server outside your network and upload it there. Or if you have a small pc left set it up in a DMZ Zone, a zone that has special access restrictions inside your company.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use SSH (scp) as a transportation and authentication method for file hosting. It's possible to keep this safe **with caution**. For example, GitHub uses SSH for transport when providing git access with the git+ssh protocol.

Now for the caution part, if you haven't done it before, it's not a trivial task.

The proper way to achieve this would be set up an isolated SSH server in a chroot environment, and set up an SSH user on this isolated SSH instance only (not a user in the system that is added by eg `useradd`). Then you can add the files that's absolutely necessary to the chroot, and provide SSH access to users.

(Nowadays you might want to consider using Linux filesystem namespaces, if applicable, to replace chroot, but I'm not sure on this.)

As for other options, setting up a simple Nginx server for static file hosting might be a lot easier, provided you have some understanding of HTTP and TLS. There're lots of writings on the Internet about this.

Both ways, if you are to expose your server to the Internet or Intranet, you need to make sure of firewalling. Consider to learn about nftables or firewalld or the like, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is moderately safe.
A better solution is to put it on a server accessible via sftp, behind a password, but also encrypt the file: in this way you introduce a double layer of protection.
On a Linux server you should be able to use a tool like gpg to encrypt your file.
Next you share the decryption key with your partners using a secure channel with e.g. an end2end encrypted messaging software.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is reasonably safe. Always keep software up-to-date.

Set up an sftp-only user with chrooted directory. In /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match User MyUser
    ChrootDirectory /var/ssh/chroot
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    X11Forwarding no
```

This user will not get a shell (because of internal-sftp), and cannot see files outside of /var/ssh/chroot.

Use a certificate client-side, additional to password.
Good description of the setup process for certificates:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server